# App crashing when image url failed in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

```
Exception caught by package:flutter_image ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FetchFailure was thrown NetworkImageWithRetry failed to load http://204.11.59.195/~automobi/aiswariaooh/uploads/images/1573712028.jpg:
FetchFailure(
  attemptCount: 1
  httpStatusCode: 404
  totalDuration: 0:00:01.143462
  originalException: null
)
```

I tried maybe solution provided in stackoverflow but my problem is not solved

```
Image(  image: NetworkImageWithRetry(img1),
        height: imageHeight, 
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this package : (https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)!: 

CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Comment: I am using this package but app gets crash when we have more 50 images each contains 200 to 300 kb images are loading in sequence using pagination 10 at a time.